# JQWidgets - Jqxgrid "no data to display", JSON Parse error

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I follow the steps of this example(http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/java-integration/bind-jquery-grid-to-mysql-database-using-jsp.htm), but there’s no data to display.

jqxgrid.jsp file:

```
ResultSet result = state.executeQuery(sql1);
JsonArray recordsArray = new JsonArray();
while (result.next()) {
    JsonObject currentRecord = new JsonObject();
    currentRecord.add("id",
            new JsonPrimitive(result.getString("id")));
    currentRecord.add("name",
            new JsonPrimitive(result.getString("name")));
    recordsArray.add(currentRecord);
}

out.print(recordsArray);
out.flush();
```

In jsp file I can get the result of JsonArray:

> [{"id":"57","name":"aa"},{"id":"58","name":"qq"},{"id":"59","name":"ii"},{"id":"60","name":"jenny"},{"id":"61","name":"candy"},{"id":"62","name":"f"},{"id":"63","name":"pp"},{"id":"66","name":"kkk"}]

jqxgrid.html file:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        
        var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [{name: 'id'}, 
                         {name: 'name'}],
           url:"jqxgrid.jsp"
        };
       
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
            downloadComplete: function (data, status, xhr) { },
            loadComplete: function (data) { },
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {alert('Status ='+ status +',  Error ='+ error ); }
        });
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
            width: 400,
            autoheight: true,
            source: dataAdapter,
            columns: [{
                text: 'ID',
                datafield: 'id',
                width: 200
            }, {
                text: 'Name',
                datafield: 'name',
                width: 200
            }]
        });
    });
```

There's grid in output but shows no data to display.
(Sorry, I can't post an image.)

Got error:

> Status =parsererror,  Error =SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `virtualMode=true` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! But still......, there's nothing change, and the grid's disappear, too.

Comment: As much as the error explains, there's a problem with the JSON built on your `jqxgrid.jsp` so try checking it careful

Comment: Also try adding `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added it in my jsp file, but still doesn't work. Is there anything wrong about building json?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not typing the source data description (client side). The id of the 4th record is 60 which happens to be the < character. The documentation said that type is a required field (though their examples don't always use it.)

If you add type `datafields:[{name:'id',type:'int'},` to the `var source = {` this may solve your problem. You could also use `'number'` as the type for id. It may pay as well to add the type `'string'` to the `name` field.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have add type to my datafields, but it's still not working. Actually I've tried lots kinds of data including jqwidget's sample database. None of those worked. Only when I use local data or remote data(like this one: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/bindingtojsonp.htm). So I think this problem probably comes from json format.

Comment: If the JSON example you provided is the one you are using there is no problem with the file. In the console you can type `JSON.parse(jsonString)` with `jsonString` being the JSON file content. Do it on a empty page and then on a jpxgrid page. They may be using a polyfill for `JSON.parse` or may have their own json parser. That is where I suspect the problem is as there is nothing wrong with your JSON string.

Comment: If that does not help, try checking the MIME type for JSON jsp file. Officially it should be `application/json` but you can also use the unofficial `text/json' or 'text/javascript' for jsp MIME types.